# Sound capture hang/freeze during v4l2 VIDIOC_QBUF calls

Tags: c++, linux, raspberry-pi, alsa, v4l2

I'm trying to capture sound with ALSA asound + video via v4l2 on raspberry pi, and separately it works fine. But on same time some audio frames loosing during VIDIOC_QBUF ioctl call:

```
ioctl(fd, VIDIOC_QBUF, &bufferinfo[i])
```

and capturing audio with

```
snd_pcm_readi (capture_handle, input_buffer_audio, audio_frames)
```

On every VIDIOC_QBUF snd_pcm_readi loose/hang for around ~300 audio frames. I'm also tried calling audio capture and video on separated test apps running on RPi, the problem also reproduced in this case.
I don't see and CPU overload or something indicating the problem (the load bellow < 12% on my RPi 3b). And the problem not reproduced on PC with linux with ALSA+v4l2 stack with the same camera (logitech c270).

On camera with 30 fps it's a big problem, because such big frames loose make sound laggy.

Comment: You probably have to show a little bit more of your code and the structure of your program. Do you capture the audio and video on different threads?

Comment: Yes, in different. But it's doesn't matter, even if audio capture and video separated to each own program VIDIOC_QBUF call from video capturing will have same slowdown effect for another process with audio capturing, and I see frame losses.
I will try to make small test example.

Comment: Are your calls (ioctl, snd_pcm_readi ) blocking or non-blocking?
I'd try non-blocking. I suspect some system wide resource that gets locked.

Comment: My initial thoughts also on some system wide locked resource that are unavailable during frame queue fill request. Both are blocking ones probably (without any NONBLOCK options pass now or something like that). But strange this is some RPi only problem and not reproduced on my linux/fedora laptop.

Comment: It is probably a bug or limitation in the kernel driver of V4L and/or ALSA specific to the Pi.